# How to place USDZ model and keep it in place when camera moving?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I have simple app where I can add objects on screen after plane detection and interact with that objects. Is it possible to add models on taped position without surface detection and keep object in that position while camera moving. I have tried to find examples but seems there is no enticing about that.

My goal is make something like `TikTok Dose`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is definitely what you want.

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                              with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.01))
        
        if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {                
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z = -0.5
            let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
            sphere.transform = SCNMatrix4(transform)                
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
        }
    }
}
```